# linking to next page when using external data not working - Ionic - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic and angularjs and i am not sure where i am going wrong. i am trying to get the json from the external link. it returns the data and displays them perfectly fine, but when i click on one of the options from the returned list it doesn't redirect to the notice details page. everything works fine if the json data is harded coded in, but i don't want that. this is the controller and service to handle the list and the links:

```
.service('NoticeboardService', function($q, $http) {
   mynotices = $http.get('http://.../app/noticeboard.php').then(function(response){    
            console.log(response.data)          
            return response.data
          })
   return {
      notices: mynotices, // if i change this so that it is hard-coded in the links work
      getNotices: function() {
      return this.notices
   },
   getNotice: function(noticeId) {
      var dfd = $q.defer()
      this.notices.forEach(function(notice) {
         if (notice.id === noticeId) dfd.resolve(notice)
      })

      return dfd.promise
   }

}
})

.controller('NoticesCtrl', function($scope, notices) {
    $scope.notices = notices
})

.controller('NoticeCtrl', function($scope, notice) {
    $scope.notice = notice
})
```

a sample from the data i am displaying:

```
[
  {

  "id": "1",
  "title": "Notice one",
  "content": null,
  "image": "uploads/news_images/2d3a24b738430c94f3.png",
  "date": "November 20, 2015, 3:19 pm"

  },
  {

  "id": "2",
  "title": "Notice Item",
  "content": null,
  "image": "uploads/news_images/6ff8308fd9f2a7baf3.png",
  "date": "November 20, 2015, 3:21 pm"

  }
]
```

when i use `console.log('notices:', mynotices);`
the following is returned: `notices: Object { $$state: Object }`
why is it not returning the array of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed the problem by changing the service to the following. To do so i used this [link](http://mcgivery.com/ionic-using-factories-and-web-services-for-dynamic-data/) to help me solve it. i'm not entirely sure why my original code didn't work but this now does:

```
.service('NoticeboardService', function($q, $http) { 

  var notices = [];

  return {
    getNotices: function(){
      return $http.get("http://fitnexus.com/app/noticeboard.php").then(function(response){
         notices = response.data;
         return notices;
      });
    },
    getNotice: function(noticeId){
      for(i=0;i<notices.length;i++){
         if(notices[i].id == noticeId){
            return notices[i];
         }
      }
      return null;
   }
 }
})
```